# Connecting to sharepoint services in hybrid apps

Tags: cordova, sharepoint, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am working on a hybrid app where I have to call Sharepoint services and get the response in XML. Can anyone post the some sample code snippet for this.